# Python Requests doesn't get the full content from a shtml page

Tags: python, python-requests, shtml

I am new to Python and try to grab the table from a shtml page. When I used `requests.get(url)`, the result was only a part of the full source code I could see from Chrome Browser and "hq_table" was not in it.

This is the code:

```py
import requests

url =  "http://www.xinfadi.com.cn/marketanalysis/2/list/1.shtml"
page_content = requests.get(url)
print(page_content.text)
```

Although it is short, I am still stuck here. Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you in advance.

Comment: When I run the code I seem to get the whole page. What part do you want that you don't get from the request?

Comment: Yep, works fine for me: `>>> 'hq_table' in requests.get("http://www.xinfadi.com.cn/marketanalysis/2/list/1.shtml").text >>> True`

Comment: Fixed. I ran it in Visual Code and it did not print out the full page content. Now I've got it. Thank you, funie200 and AKX